# How to calculate time difference on column value change?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to get the accumulated time difference with respect to a value change in a column in SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to gather some analytics on how much time a task was pending on another user, in this task there are 2 participants Role = 0 is the implementer and Role = 1 is the reviewer of the task. Through the duration of the task the implementer and the the reviewer can perform activities on the task multiple times. The aim is to to get the total time it was pending for the reviewer and the implementer.
To re create a snapshot of the data please see the example below

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityTable
([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RoleId] [int] NULL,
[ActivityDate] [DATETIME] NULL)

INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-19 13:00:19.840')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-19 13:00:18.073')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-19 12:59:48.417')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 13:48:00.557')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:56:25.567')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:56:09.967')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:55:26.500')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:53:17.997')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-15 12:36:17.967')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-15 12:35:38.497')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-15 12:33:05.860')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-15 12:32:07.793')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (1, '2018-10-15 12:32:00.010')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:18:18.417')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:17:16.370')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 12:11:48.590')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 11:58:38.557')
INSERT INTO [ActivityTable] VALUES (0, '2018-10-15 11:56:23.820')`
```

So the total time for each transition would look like

```
RoleInfo  Start Time               End Time                 Duration Minutes
0         2018-10-15 11:56:23.820  2018-10-15 12:32:00.010  37
1         2018-10-15 12:32:00.010  2018-10-15 12:53:17.997  22
0         2018-10-15 12:53:17.997  2018-10-19 12:59:48.417  5767
1         2018-10-19 12:59:48.417  2018-10-19 13:00:19.840  1
```

and the final result expected is aggregation of pending times

```
RoleInfo  Duration in Minutes
0         5804
1         23
```

Comment: From the transition total time table (table 2 in your e.g.), it looks like there are two tasks that went through the implementer and reviewer phases. How do you know which ActivityTable record belongs to which task?

Answer (score 0):

refer to comments within the query.

execute each inner query by itself to see the result for better understanding

```
select  RoleId, Duration = sum(datediff(minute, StartTime, EndTime))
from
(
    -- perform a group by RoleId + grp
    -- min() and max() on ActivityDate will gives you based on RoleId
    -- however you wanted the StartTime of next RoleId. For this LEAD() OVER() is used
    select  RoleId, 
            StartTime = min(ActivityDate), 
            EndTime   = coalesce(lead(min(ActivityDate)) over (order by min(ActivityDate)), 
                                 max(ActivityDate))
    from
    (
        -- identify the group. each group is continuous same RoleId value
        select  *, grp = Id - dense_rank() over (partition by RoleId 
                                                     order by ActivityDate desc)
        from    ActivityTable
    ) a
    group by RoleId, grp
) b
group by RoleId
```

by the way, i think the expected result that you posted is wrong

```
/* RESULT
    RoleId  Duration
    0       5802
    1       22
*/
```

Comment: Awesome, that gives me the result I was looking for. Thank you